# How to save HTML file rendered from markdown with PlantUML diagrams with IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, markdown, plantuml

Here is what I want to do with **IntelliJ**:

**1.** Edit markdown with some **PlantUML** diagrams while checking rendered preview image

**2.** Save the result of **1** as rendered HTML file.

I can do **1** with **PlantUML Integration** plugin,
but I can't do **2** though I can save each UML diagram as png file from **PlantUML** Tool Windows.
Is there  a way to do **2**?

(I use IntelliJ IDEA COMMUNITY 2019.3)

I know it can be done with **VSCode** by **Markdown Preview Enhanced** extension,
but I wonder if **IntelliJ** can do same thing as **VSCode** since I usually use **IntelliJ**.

Answer (score 0):

It is not yet supported. Please vote for [IDEA-105879](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-105879) request.